# Kubernetes Master API SERVER IP

Tags: kubernetes, devops, configuration-management

I've k8s cluster and pod which one living in there . 
So ,  I have got a requirements for pod process .

Pod need a Cluster Ip for manage some jobs . How I can set the API Server name as a Environment variable .

My Pod Yaml shown as below :

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
  name: api-server-check
 spec:
  containers:
   - name: container-1
   image: project_reg/pod:latest
   env:
    - name: MY_NODE_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: spec.nodeName
    - name: CLUSTER_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: ???????? ### Problem is here I think .
```

If you have another suggestion for me , I will apply it to the Pod yaml . (Shell script or etc .. )

Thanks

Comment: you don't need to, you always can access the api server with it's name "kubernetes"

Comment: you need service's cluster IP. Am I right??

Comment: service need the API_SERVER ip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cluster internal DNS to point to the Kubernetes API Server.
The API Service should already be exposed as a service called "kubernetes" in the default namespace.
`kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` should resolve to the API server.

Also, if you dump the `env` inside a running pod you should see that there is an environment variable which already has this information... `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST`